# RStudio editor: How to skip closing brackets that are autogenerated

Tags: r, rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts

When you start typing an opening bracket such as [({, RStudio autocompletes the corresponding closing bracket which is nice. But how do you skip over those closing brackets to end the line or resume writing some more after?
You can surely use a mouse or arrow (>) to move forward, but I am looking for a simple shortcut. If I use Ctr + e, the cursor moves to the end of the line like any other popular editors. This is not solution particularly to my problem because I just want to skip the closing brackets.

Comment: what about ctrl + right ?

Comment: That seems to take the cursor to the end of the line. Does RStudio have a shortcut to skip one word?

Comment: try alt + right ?

Answer (score 0):

I think Ctr + e to move the cursor to the end of the line does what I want because after you type something inside of the brackets, you would start typing after the closing brackets which is the end of the line anyway.
But in particular case you may want to only two closing bracket inside of three brackets. Then it would be convenient to have a shortcut that gets the cursor out of the current bracket.